# JQuery fadeIn() on DOM element creation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, element

How do I create a DOM element in JQuery and fade it in to show up, instead of having it show up immediately?

I try this:

```
var myDiv = "<div>Hello!</div>"
$("somePlace").after(myDiv).fadeIn('fast');
```

but this doesn't work, since the .after(myDiv) makes it popup immediately. Any solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
$("<div>Hello</div>").hide().appendTo("somePlace").fadeIn("fast");
```

Comment: Thanks cletus! Thanks altCognito for the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Add it with a class that is hidden at the start.

```
<style>
  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<div class="hidden">
  Won't be seen.
</div>
```